# Reactivate a user with full access

Tags: user-management

I have recently started a new contract with an organisation I was working with last year. We have reactivated my Salesforce account with the same email address as was used last time, however I now only have Chatter functionality, and need access to our full Salesforce suite. Is there some step we have missed in reactivation?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the license.

Comment: Better if you can edit your question and add user record details like profile and license name.

Answer (score 1):

As @AdrianLarson mentioned in his comment, it's a licenses assignment issue.

You need to select the "Salesforce" User License when adding / reactivating a user:

[image]

If you don't see the Salesforce option, it means you've used all your full Salesforce license and need to purchase more, or adjust it from a different active user.

You may need to deactivate the user first before being able to adjust their User License.